# What is the best way to get and element in HTML by the text between the tags?

Tags: javascript, html

How can I find all elements with a specific string between the tags?

```
<foo>
    <bar>sadfkwai foobar sapkdajda?</bar>
</foo>
```

Also, if after finding where the element is, if I could scope out until an element ´foo´

Comment: What have you tried? What causes the problem? Can you select `bar` elements? Can you get the text of an element? Can you test if a string contains another string? Can you get the parent of an element?

Comment: Use `document.querySelectorAll("foo")` to find all `<foo>` elements. Use `.innerText` to get its text content. Use string functions to search for `2019`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `document.getElementsByTagName` to find `<foo>` elements.

Iterate over them, and remove if its content includes `2019`:

```js
for (const foo of document.getElementsByTagName('foo'))
  if(foo.innerText.includes('2019'))
    foo.parentNode.removeChild(foo)
```

If you have to do this only with the first element containing `2019`, break the loop if it's found:

```js
for (const foo of document.getElementsByTagName('foo'))
  if(foo.innerText.includes('2019')) {
    foo.parentNode.removeChild(foo)
    break 
  }
```